# SocialEngine4: Notification Error: Zend Engine_Api_Exception with message Unknown item type

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using socialengine4 and my notifications keep giving me this error. I thought this was some type of config thing and look into the database or the notifications setting but i have not been able to fix this error. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
2012-05-22T17:40:21+00:00 CRIT (2): 
Error Code: dc0cf5
exception 'Engine_Api_Exception' with message 'Unknown item type: news_content' in /var/www/html/application/libraries/Engine/Api.php:417
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/application/libraries/Engine/Api.php(522): Engine_Api->getItemInfo('news_content', 'moduleInflected')
#1 /var/www/html/application/libraries/Engine/Api.php(330): Engine_Api->getItemApi('news_content')
#2 /var/www/html/application/modules/Activity/Model/Notification.php(80): Engine_Api->getItem('news_content', 2622)
#3 /var/www/html/application/modules/Activity/Model/Notification.php(49): Activity_Model_Notification->getObject()
#4 /var/www/html/application/modules/Activity/Model/Notification.php(98): Activity_Model_Notification->getContent()
#5 /var/www/html/application/modules/Activity/views/scripts/notifications/pulldown.tpl(17): Activity_Model_Notification->__toString()
#6 /var/www/html/application/libraries/Zend/View.php(108): include('/var/www/html/a...')
#7 /var/www/html/application/libraries/Zend/View/Abstract.php(835): Zend_View->_run('/var/www/html/a...')
#8 /var/www/html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(903): Zend_View_Abstract->render('notifications/p...')
#9 /var/www/html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(924): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->renderScript('notifications/p...', NULL)
#10 /var/www/html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(964): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->render()
#11 /var/www/html/application/modules/Activity/controllers/NotificationsController.php(109): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->postDispatch()
#12 /var/www/html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action.php(512): Activity_NotificationsController->pulldownAction()
#13 /var/www/html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(289): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('pulldownAction')
#14 /var/www/html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Front.php(946): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#15 /var/www/html/application/modules/Core/Bootstrap.php(75): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#16 /var/www/html/application/libraries/Engine/Application.php(160): Core_Bootstrap->run()
#17 /var/www/html/application/index.php(194): Engine_Application->run()
#18 /var/www/html/index.php(24): include('/var/www/html/a...')
#19 {main}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings for the items are in Application->modules->'modulename'->settings>manifest.php

There is an array called items which i added 'news_content' to and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it.

The problem was that somehow (despite lack of enable/disable link on the module box in the list of modules) it was disabled.

To enable it I accessed the 'engine4_core_modules' table, searched for 'storage' name and changed the 'enabled' cell content from 0 to 1.